# Spring Security + LDAP Authentication- org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I am using Spring Security where I have to authenticate the User from AD. Currently I have a login Form, Where when i provide correct login credentials it validates properly and after login it redirects to landing page. However if I provide wrong credential I am getting Following exception-

```
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.GPPortal.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece]]
```

Please Help me resolving this exception as I am stuck with this from a long time.

This is my Spring-security.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.svc.gp" />

<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    class="com.svc.gp.customExceptionHandler.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <constructor-arg value="/GP/login"></constructor-arg>

</bean>
<!-- redirect url for failure of authentication -->
<!-- <bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"> 
    <constructor-arg value="/login.jsp?error=1"></constructor-arg> </bean> -->

<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
    access-denied-page="/GP/denied">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/GP/welcome"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/GP/login"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/GP/landing"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/GP/test"
        access="permitAll" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/GP/login"
        default-target-url="/GP/test" authentication-failure-url="/GP/login?authfailed=true" />

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/GP/login" logout-url="/GP/logout" />

</security:http>

<!-- For authentication: user-search-filter: the attribute name that contains 
    the user name user-search-base: the base path where to find user information 
    For authorization: group-search-filter: the attribute name that contains 
    the full dn of a user group-search-base: the base path where to find role 
    information group-role-attribute: the attribute name that contains the role 
    type role-prefix: the prefix to be added when retrieving role values For 
    server access: manager-dn: the full dn of the person that has access to an 
    LDAP server manager-password: the password of the person that has access 
    to an LDAP server -->
<security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="(uid={0})" 
        user-search-base="ou=users" group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})" group-search-base="ou=groups" 
        group-role-attribute="cn" role-prefix="ROLE_"> </security:ldap-authentication-provider> -->

    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />

    <!-- For Roles against database -->
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- <security:ldap-server url="ldap://172.28.26.135:10389/o=fulcrum,dc=fulcrum,dc=com" 
    manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" manager-password="secret" /> -->

<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="abc.com" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://************" />
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
</bean>
```

my CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.java

```
package com.svc.gp.customExceptionHandler;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import  org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException;

public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

private boolean forwardToDestination;
private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy;

public CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    super();
}

public CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler(String defaultFailureUrl) {
    super(defaultFailureUrl);
    System.out.println("defaultFailureUrl::" +defaultFailureUrl);
}

/*  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    if (this.defaultFailureUrl == null) {
        this.logger
                .debug("No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized  error");
        response.sendError(401,
                "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
    } else {
        saveException(request, exception);

        if (this.forwardToDestination) {
            this.logger.debug("Forwarding to " + this.defaultFailureUrl);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(this.defaultFailureUrl).forward(
                    request, response);
        } else {
            this.logger.debug("Redirecting to " +  this.defaultFailureUrl);
            this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response,
                    this.defaultFailureUrl);
        }
    }
}*/

public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {    

        if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(BadCredentialsException.class)) {
              setDefaultFailureUrl("/url1");
        }

       else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(DisabledException.class)) {        
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/url2");
       }

       else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(SessionAuthenticationException.class)) {      
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/url3");  
      }

      super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);  
    }
```

}

Here is my login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Genius Plus Portal Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    Exception error = (Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute(
            "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION");
    if (error != null)
        out.write(error.getMessage());
%>

<form action="../j_spring_security_check" method="POST">

    <p>
        <label for="j_username">Username</label> <input id="j_username"
            name="j_username" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="j_password">Password</label> <input id="j_password"
            name="j_password" type="password" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />

</form>

</body>
</html>


Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: It looks like your username/password is not coorect `javax.naming.AuthenticationException`.

Comment: Jens- when i enter wrong username/password I am getting the exception. I need to handle that exception and come to login page again. Can you tell how to do?